# What are the current House's bill reconciliation rules regarding deficit increases?

Tags: united-states, budget, house-of-representatives

According to The Center on Budget and Policy page, ["Introduction to Budget 'Reconciliation'"](https://www.cbpp.org/research/federal-budget/introduction-to-budget-reconciliation):

> When Republicans took the House in 2011, they replaced the House rule with one that placed no restrictions on revenue provisions that increase deficits but prohibited reconciliation instructions that would produce a net increase in mandatory spending, regardless of the reconciliation bill’s overall impact on deficits.

Since [Democrats obtained a majority in the House in 2018](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/kidspost/election-2018-democrats-take-over-house-majority-republicans-make-gains-in-senate/2018/11/07/1130dea2-e298-11e8-8f5f-a55347f48762_story.html), have any of the house reconciliation rules changed/introduced in 2011 been altered or removed by the Democratic majority? I have been looking everywhere online but have not been able to find an answer to this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the current House's bill reconciliation rules regarding deficit increases?

[Budget Enforcement Procedures: House Pay-As-You-Go (PAYGO) Rule](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R41510.pdf), Updated August 12, 2019.

> **Actions in the 116 th Congress**
>
> At the beginning of the 116th Congress, in adopting the rules of the House, the new Democratic majority reinstituted the PAYGO rule, replacing the previous CUTGO rule.<sup>21</sup> Most significantly, the PAYGO rule reincorporates the projected revenue effects of legislation into the evaluation of determining a violation. The new rule, however, is not exactly the same PAYGO rule that existed at the end of the 111th Congress. In particular, unlike the previous PAYGO rule, it includes off-budget effects, such as those that affect the receipts and outlays of the Social Security trust funds.
>
> In general, other than these changes, the new House PAYGO rule retains the procedures related to the operation of the former CUTGO and PAYGO rules. For example, the new PAYGO rule continues to provide for combining the budgetary effects of two measures, under particular circumstances, and for excluding budgetary effects designated as an emergency, as described in the “Features of the House PAYGO Rule,” section above.

---

> <sup>21</sup> On the opening day of the 116th Congress, January 3, 2019, the House agreed to H.Res. 5, which provided for the consideration of H.Res. 6 (i.e., the opening-day rules package) and divided the question of adopting the resolution into three parts, each part consisting of one of its three titles. The first title adopted the Standing Rules of the 115th Congress, with certain amendments, which included amending House Rule XXI to replace clause 10 with the current PAYGO rule. On January 3, the House agreed to Title I of H.Res. 6 by a vote of 234-197. For the consideration and adoption of Title I of H.Res. 6, including a section-by-section analysis of the changes by the majority staff of the House Rules Committee, see Congressional Record, daily edition, vol. 165 (January 3, 2019), pp. H17-H32.

---

H.Res. 6, [Pay-As-You-Go Point Of Order](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-resolution/6/text#H93C697784D0E4DA8BE2D22110CF4B08C) has the significant changes to [RULES of the HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES](http://clerk.house.gov/legislative/house-rules.pdf) concerning reconciliation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, no changes have been made. [According to house.gov](https://budget.house.gov/publications/fact-sheet/budget-reconciliation-basics), the Republican rule change in 2011 seems to be the most recent rule change. The only recent times it has come up since then is when Republicans used it in 2017:

> ...That rule change allowed Congress to again use the reconciliation process to increase deficits, which the Republican majority did in 2017.
>
> In the 115th Congress, Republicans used reconciliation to enact their tax law. In the final months of 2017, the House and Senate approved a reconciliation measure (H.R. 1) to cut taxes mostly for the wealthy and corporations and to eliminate the penalty for not having health insurance. The Congressional Budget Office estimated at the time that the legislation would add $1.5 trillion to federal deficits over 10 years. President Trump signed this legislation into law on December 22, 2017. Earlier in that same year, Republicans attempted to use reconciliation to dismantle the Affordable Care Act. The House approved a reconciliation measure (H.R. 1628) to repeal major provisions of the health care law and cap federal funding for Medicaid, but the Senate failed to get the needed votes to advance a bill.

But as far as changes to that rule, none seem to have been made since.